# Python Email attachment loses end-of-newline "\n"

Tags: python, email, format, attachment

My python script (as the following) can send a ".txt" attachment, but unfortunately the received attachment lost the "\n", so all lines are together which ruined my column format. Can anyone please give me a help? Thanks a lot!

```
msg['From'] = send_from
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = 'Subject of Email4'

mailbody = "This is the content of Email4"
msg.attach(MIMEText(mailbody))

with open("regresult.txt", "r") as fil:
    part = MIMEApplication(
        fil.read(),
        Name=basename("regresult.txt")
    )
    part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename('regresult.txt')
    msg.attach(part)
```

Update: The original file (opened in remote Unix server with VIM) is like this:[original file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kulWe.jpg)

The received file format is like this: [received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHexS.jpg)

Comment: can you show the resulting attachment text? and the original text?

Comment: I think the problem is with the text file itself. The above code is pretty straight forward. `MIMEApplication` simply encodes the text file using base64 and the email client viewing the email decodes it, no complications there. I did have some issues with opening text files in windows and the new line characters were missing for me.  Try using `unix2dos` or `dos2unix` before attaching the .txt file

Comment: @joelgoldstick, I can only upload images of the two formats. Couldn't find place to upload .txt attachement.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @gixxer's hint. It is the format problem of the txt file itself. The end-of-line character in the original txt is "\n" which works well on Unix system, but not on Windows. Windows uses "\r\n" instead. So I just add "\r\n" to the end of each line in the original file, and then it works.